# Remove values above data line iOS Charts

Tags: ios, swift, charts

I have built a small application to measure Heart Rate (HR) and currently trying to implement a chart using iOS Charts. It is working as intended (getting HR from watch and displaying it), but I have a small problem with the design of the chart.

On the image below you can see that I have overlapping numbers above the data line (70, and the later 90). I do not know how to remove them.

[Chart Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0PAwT.jpg)

Here is my setup for the chart and its' update counter function:

```
    //chart set up
    self.chtChart.delegate = self as? ChartViewDelegate
    let set_a: LineChartDataSet = LineChartDataSet(entries:[ChartDataEntry(x: Double(0), y: self.valueHR)], label: "HR")
    set_a.drawCirclesEnabled = false
    set_a.setColor(UIColor.systemPink)

    self.chtChart.xAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = false
    self.chtChart.rightAxis.drawLabelsEnabled = false
    self.chtChart.xAxis.drawLabelsEnabled = false

    self.chtChart.data = LineChartData(dataSets: [set_a])

    // update counter
    var i = 1
    @objc func updateCounter() {
        self.chtChart.data?.addEntry(ChartDataEntry(x: Double(i), y: valueHR), dataSetIndex: 0)
        self.chtChart.setVisibleXRange(minXRange: Double(0), maxXRange: Double(1000))
        self.chtChart.notifyDataSetChanged()
        self.chtChart.moveViewToX(Double(i))
        i = i + 1
    }
```

I know that there is a duplicate question, but the solution with the formatter did not help me: nothing was changed after the implementation of the solution.
[formatter solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44186683/ios-charts-remove-decimal-from-yvalues)

Comment: Does setting `drawValuesEnabled = false` remove them?

Comment: No. It does not.

Comment: My mistake. I was looking at `drawLabelsEnabled = false ` on the axis. Your solution helped! Thank you very much!